# Symbolising the set of pupils who do not like both subjects

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic-translation

If $A= \{\text{pupils who like Science}\}$, $B= \{\text{pupils who like History}\},$ then is the set of pupils who do not like both subjects $$(A\cap B)^\complement$$ or $$(A\cup B)^\complement\,?$$

Comment: What does "pupil who does not like both subjects" mean? Does that pupil like _neither Science nor History_? Or is the pupil allowed to like (at most) one of Science and History - but not both? In the first case, the answer is $(A\cup B)'$ and in the second it is $(A\cap B)'$.

Answer (score 2):

> If $A= \{\text{pupils who like Science}\}$, $B= \{\text{pupils who like History}\},$ then is the set of pupils who *do not like both subjects* $$(A\cap B)^\complement$$ or $$(A\cup B)^\complement\,?$$

1. $(A\cap B)$ is the set of pupils who like both subjects, so its complement $\boldsymbol{(A\cap B)^\complement}$ is the set of pupils who **like at most one subject**.
2. The phrase ‘neither A nor B’ literally means ‘not (either A nor B)’, so $\boldsymbol{(A\cup B)^\complement}$ is the set of pupils who likes neither subject, which is precisely the set $(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)$ of pupils who **dislike both subjects**.

Your phrasing ‘*not like both*’ ambiguously could mean either of the above: is the negation ‘not’ being applied

1. to the phrase ‘like both’  (so, **not (like both)**)

or

2. to the word ‘like’  (so, **dislike both**) ?

This is analogous to the difference between these sentences:

1. $¬∀x\, Lx$
2. $∀x\, ¬Lx\quad (\equiv ¬∃x\,Lx).$

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is ambiguous. It could have either of the two suggested meanings.